# How to search a file ending with .doc or .docx in ftp server and download all the files by using java code

Tags: java, ftp

On ftp server I have access to AB and its child folders. My ftp url will be some thing like this- ftp://servername:portnumber/AB/. There are my sub folders under AB. Now I have to search all the files which are ending with .doc and .docx and download it.

public class test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ftpUrl = "ftp://servername:21/AB";
    System.out.println("URL: " + ftpUrl);

try {
    URL url = new URL(ftpUrl);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    String line = null;
    System.out.println("--- START ---");
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    System.out.println("--- END ---");
    inputStream.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

}

The above code is displaying all the folders under AB. Now how can I search a files ending with .doc and download them.
As I am beginner to java, I am finding some difficulty in doing this task.